# DS-5 example code

Tags: arm, ds-5, streamline

I have been trying to find DS-5 example code. Does DS-5 have example code showing how to use different features? If yes, how can I get access to it? And what does the sample code cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, DS-5 does have some sample code.

The page https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/sample-code contains high level information on the code available. The code contains bare-metal (no operating system) and Linux OS app examples. It also has few examples related to TrustZone, DTSL, Linux kernel module debugging and other features.

However, the sample code, by itself, is **NOT** available for download online. You need to install DS-5 to get it, as the sample code is part of the installation. An 30 day eval version can be downloaded from https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/downloads. The example code is **NOT** part of DS-5 as a plugin installation.

The examples, by default, do not appear in the DS-5 workspace. You have to import it by following the instructions in https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/importing-ds-5-example-projects